# How to routing Index using Django app with one request?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have made myself a nice little Django app, but I recently understand when Index page is requested, 2 request sent to Django, I found where is the problem but I don't have any solution for it.

project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
]
```

myapp urls.py:

```
app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

When I request: http://127.0.0.1:8000, first Django check this line:

```
path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
```

and after map myapp urls, check this line:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

so 2 requests has processed, as show in console:

```
[06/Jul/2018 14:28:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11904
[06/Jul/2018 14:28:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11904
```

how can solve this problem? anybody know?

Comment: clear console once again hit url , it should be once,make sure you did not open the same url in another tab or browser

Comment: What are you using to do the request? It is possible that whatever tool/browser you are using is sending two requests for some reason.

Comment: I'm sure, I had checked it several times, it's happen just in index page. @HemanthSP

Comment: I'm send request from browser. I know problem is from routing, for example when I change `path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),` to `path('myapp\', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),` it's okay. @ritlew

Comment: Its weird... for me only process just 1 request... this 2 paths its just setting the Url chain of your project... /<app>/<modelsUrl>/... (the <app> is defined at your project urls and <modelsUrls> and ... is defined by you apps urls>

Comment: @MajidRouhi try changing `path('', views.index, name='index'),` to `path('/', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: I even try this, but get 404. @ritlew

Comment: I can't understand why this happen. @DiegoVinícius

Comment: Try curl your project or use postman, and check if you receive 2 requests or just one...

Comment: open your terminal and curl http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: with Postman it's send 1 request. It's seem problem is in templates. I'm found it :) @DiegoVinícius

Comment: ok, maybe something in your template is recalling the request :D

Comment: yes it's, solved :D, an image tag is recalling the request. Tnx @DiegoVinícius

Comment: nope, just posted one answer, if it in fact helped you please mark as anwer and upvote, tks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in your project is to setup your Chain Url Tree in your router

```
path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
```

tells that every request at '' path will be handled by myapp urls

while

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

tells that '/' path will be handled by index view

Example:

```
path('blog', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
path('chat', include('chat.urls', namespace='chat')),
```

with that code you set your tree like

```
|_ blog
|_ chat
```

**in your blog.url**

```
path('post', views.post, name='post'),
path('comment', views.comment, name='comment'),
```

**in your chat.url**

```
path('room', views.room, name='room'),
path('message', views.message, name='message'),
```

Will give you this tree

```
|_ blog
|____ post
|____ comment
|_ chat
|____ room
|____ message
```

So.... /blog/post/ and /chat/room/

That setups dont make your application do multiple requests in same urls.

Do **cUrl or send one request with PostMan to check if your server receive 1 or more requests**... if it receive just one request the problem is something arround your template, maybe something is calling it twice, maybe ajax...